# Play .ogg OR .mp3 files in jplayer

Tags: jquery, jplayer

I am trying to use a particular audio file to play when a page loads.  The problem is, I do not know how to get jplayer to play EITHER .mp3 or .ogg.

Firefox supports .ogg, but Safari and IE do not.

Therefore, I want the audio to play whatever file format the users browser supports.

Here is the code in my .js file:

```
$f("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function (event) {
            $f(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                oga:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-07-Bubble.ogg"
            }).jPlayer("play");
        },
        swfPath: "js",
        solution: 'html, flash',
        supplied: "m4a, oga",
        wmode: "window"
    });

    $f("#jquery_jplayer_2").jPlayer({
        ready: function (event) {
            $f(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                oga:"http://www.davidhornbrook.com/chad/test3/template/David.ogg"
            }).jPlayer("play");
        },
        swfPath: "js",
        solution: 'html, flash',
        supplied: "m4a, oga",
        wmode: "window"
    });

    $f("#jquery_jplayer_3").jPlayer({
        ready: function (event) {
            $f(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                mp3:"http://www.davidhornbrook.com/chad/test3/template/David.mp3"
            }).jPlayer("play");
        },
        swfPath: "js",
        solution: 'html, flash',
        supplied: "mp3",
        wmode: "window"
    });
```

The code in the .html file is this:

```
<div id="controls-wrapper" class="load-item">
                <div id="controls">
                    <a id="prevslide" class="load-item"></a>
                    <a id="play-button"><img id="pauseplay" src="img/pause.png" alt="fashion" /></a>
                    <a id="nextslide" class="load-item"></a>
                </div>
                <div id="jquery_jplayer_2" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
                <div id="jp_container_1" class="jp-audio">
                    <ul class="jp-controls">
                        <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-play" tabindex="1">play</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-pause" tabindex="1">pause</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I am sure there is a way to do this, but I am at a loss right now.  ANY help would be appreciated.
You may email me directly at chad at hornbook.com

---------EDIT-------------

I have done this as a stopgap measure.  In the html code I added this:

```
        <!-- Content -->
        <div class="content">
        <img src="img/HBLogo903.png" />
        </div>




<audio autoplay="">
  <source src="David.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
  <source src="David.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio>



        <!-- /Content -->
```

Not an ideal situation by any means and I do not know if it will work in IE 6/7/8
I do have this as the first line in my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Thanks everyone for any help :)